# What is the simplest way to format numbers that exist between texts?

Tags: java

What is the simplest way to format numbers that exist between texts?

```
String s1 = "1128 ... 9812"; //What I have
            "1,128 ... 9,812" //Expected result

String s2 = "823446 ... 26 ... 239173"; //What I have
            "823,446 ... 26 ... 239,173" //Expected result

String s3 = "8012332 ... 7283912011"; //What I have
            "8,012,332 ... 7,283,912,011" //Expected result
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Extract the numbers, rebuild the string with the formatted numbers. No magic shortcut.

Comment: @RickyMo Yes, I know how to do it myself but with many steps, I thought there is a function that can do that with one line, Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one-liner which does the task, but if you need to do this reapetedly you could declare a method/function/UnaryOperator and reuse it. (Assuming all your numbers fit in a long)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("###,###");
    UnaryOperator<String> function = s -> {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{4,}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, nf.format(Long.parseLong(m.group())));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    };

    String s1 = "1128 ... 9812"; //What I have        "1,128 ... 9,812" //Expected result
    String s2 = "823446 ... 26 ... 239173"; //What I have        "823,446 ... 26 ... 239,173" //Expected result
    String s3 = "8012332 ... 7283912011"; //What I have        "8,012,332 ... 7,283,912,011" //Expected result

    s1 = function.apply(s1);
    s2 = function.apply(s2);
    s3 = function.apply(s3);

    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s2);
    System.out.println(s3);
}
```